# Showing vertical bar when splitting in GNU Screen

Tags: gnu-screen

I use the cygwin version of GNU screen (Screen version 4.00.03 (FAU) 23-Oct-06) where I can vertically split the screen into left and right windows.  But I couldn't find any commands to show a vertical bar to show where the screen is split.  Is there a way to show something similar to the horizontal bar when you split the screen into top and bottom halves?

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this by adding the following line to your ~/.screenrc:

- hardstatus alwayslastline "%1`"

also, a tip; i'd recommend ***"ctrl-a |"*** rather than **"ctrl a S"** for a vertical split, than a horizontal one. this is my personal preference, which just happens to already include a divider bar.

make sure you're using the latest version of GNU Screen

/tips hat

Comment: err...it did not work, I modified `hardstatus alwayslastline "%{.bW}%-w%{.rW}%n %t%{-}%+w %=%{..G} %H %{..Y} %m/%d %C%a "` that I already had in my `.screenrc` with a `%1` at the end and it didn't work.  Does it work with the version I mentioned in my post above?

Comment: Is this still an issue?

Answer (score 0):

### https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dFdqyccdWUE on minute 2:00 that would be a solution

1. Ctrl-a S   #create another windows
2. Ctrl-a Tab #moving from another windows
3. Ctrl-a c   #create new session
4. Ctrl-a |   #splitting vertical